# Unit Test C# [TestInitialize] problem on parallel execution?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am performing Unit Tests in C# - In theory I learned to use `[TestInitialize]` to avoid redundand code. Back in office I made something like this.

```
class Tests {
APIContext apicon;
Controller controller;

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    apicon = new APIContext();
    controller = new relevantController(cRep);
    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
}
```

I got a comment from a collegue that Tests run in parallel on Build Server. The method `TestInitialize()` will be executed before every test that executes. Therefore the fields may be reinitialised while a test is running.

Is this true or false? I also read that when you run the tests in parallel the runner will create an instance of the TestClass for each Thread, so the fields won't be touched while a test is running?

Comment: Every test method will firstly call TestInitialize. 
If it has the ability to run in parallel, a proper instance will be created.
I would like to suggest, if you have some weird behaviors or move the configuration or instantiation to inside the Test method on Arrange block.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes i moved it to the Arrange block. I am only really interested if it can cause strange behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its correct method with [TestInitialize] attribute will get called before executing any TestMethod. You can refer this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/test-initialize-and-test-setup/) for better understanding of [TestInitialize] and [TestSetup] attributes

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this is not really my question. I know that it is called before each TestMethod. I want to know if there can be strange behaviour with parallel execution.

Comment: @VEJ Did you get any answer on your question? I am also looking for answer. I ran my tests in parallel which share same configuration object with different state but couldn't produce any strange behavior.  The thing I don't know if there is only single reference and testinitialize is assigning the different heap memory how 2 parallel tests able to still use them..  
Why one won't override other reference?

Comment: @user1136425 No i am sorry. Also CleanUp should have strange behaviour, then. But really hard to test. Cause it could happen  one of hundred times. If the runner will create an instance of the TestClass for each Thread, one won´t override other references. But care if you have file access. Then may better avoid  [TestInitialize].